# Hadoop: Compressing output of Map-only job

Tags: java, compression, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a a map-only job that outputs in TextOutputFormat.

I currently see three ways of compressing my output:

1. by defining map to compress through mapred.compress.map.output.*
2. by defining output to compress through mapred.output.compression.*
3. by defining the TextOutputFormat to compress through TextOutputFormat.setCompressOutput()
4. by composing one or more of the first 3 possibilities.

Any insight on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is ONLY for intermediate output, Option 2 works as well but is more of a mapred-site.xml approach, Option 3 is the way to go.

Comment: Is there any advantage (3) provides over (2)? (2) and (3) should be fine.

Comment: i don't think there's an advantage. one is meant for a node-level configuration (still overridable by the job) while the other is a job-level configuration.

Comment: I think, (2) and (3) are job level configurations only. How can compression be configured at a node level?

Comment: Why not? The idea would be that by default the node compresses the output of all the task it runs, so that it doesn't have to be set by jobs. it would describe the node behavior.